# Where are the transistor number 18 and 21 in op amp 741 according to Wikipedia?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, diodes, bjt, oscillator

I was trying to implement [this op amp](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/OpAmpTransistorLevel_Colored_Labeled.svg/500px-OpAmpTransistorLevel_Colored_Labeled.svg.png) from Wikipedia in Proteus :

[image]

Like this:

[image]

But I could not find Q number 18 and 21.

What is the reason that there are not Q number 18 and 21? Or if this image is incorrect, how can I find the correct transistor model of op amp 741?

Also this professor uses this model:

And I do not know why there are two Q15!

https://youtu.be/GXCsDRKJPag?t=444

[image]

My understanding about Q and its number is the number of transistors.

Comment: Maybe those transistors were removed from an earlier version? When I delete unnecessary components from a schematic I will usually not renumber.

Comment: @Bart - When you do that, do you make a note that Qxx is not used?

Comment: I make a component list to keep track of that

Answer (score 1):

Compare the circuits in datasheets from different manufacturers:

https://eecs.oregonstate.edu/education/docs/datasheets/LM741.pdf

https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/ua741.pdf

https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ua741.pdf

There are versions with missing Q-numbers and there is a version without any Q-number. There is also a version with two Q15. I did not find a version without missing numbers or double numbers.

Here is a version with missing Q19 and Q21:

https://cdn.evilmadscientist.com/KitInstrux/741/741_datasheet_rev20d.pdf

Comment: +1 For digging up all these fossils. ;)

Comment: I am assuming you are talking about an integrated circuit. Generally the published schematics are equivalent drawings, not actual drawings. Many manufacturers will label them as such.